# Open file in Vim terminal session upon shortcut

Tags: shortcut-keys, gnome-terminal, shortcuts

I have a bunch of files that I make small edits too all throughout my day.

They are each in their own directory within a common super directory, e.g.:

```
test
├── foo
│   └── foo.tex
└── bar
    └── bar.tex
```

Is it possible to create a shortcut, such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> such that if enter that shortcut and then sufficiently many initial letters and then hit enter the corresponding file (in the directory of the same name)  get's opened in a vim session in the terminal?

If not, is there something close to it? Creating a different shortcut for each file would be acceptable but not optimal because it is around 10 files, so all the shortcuts would be hard to remember (and they would take up shortcut space)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. I stored the following Python script in my home directory and created a shortcut to it using compizconfig-settings-manager. The main directory (`~/test` in my example) and the file endings of the files to be edited (`.tex` in my example) may be changed in the script.

```
ROOTDIR = '~/test'
FILEENDING = '.tex'
import subprocess
import re
import os
import tkinter
import tkinter.simpledialog
def string_dialog(title,label):
    root = tkinter.Tk()
    root.withdraw()
    return tkinter.simpledialog.askstring(title, label)
project = string_dialog('Quickedit','Enter filename')
regexp = re.compile(project+'.*',re.IGNORECASE)
choices = [path for path in os.listdir(ROOTDIR) if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(rootdir,path)) and path.lower().startswith(project.lower())]
projectdir = os.path.join(ROOTDIR,choices[0])
projectfile = [path for path in os.listdir(projectdir) if path.endswith(FILEENDING)][0]
subprocess.call(['gvim',os.path.join(projectdir,projectfile)])
```